# How to return the Json value using WCF WebApi

Tags: json, wcf-web-api

I have create a one sample WCF rest template WebApi in this i have use Entity Framework to getting the data when i run the service for it return the string value it showing the result but at end of the json value add XML code like below how can i solve this.

```
[{"AccountId":1,
  "AccountNumber":"AC001",
  "AccountType":"Restaurant",
  "BusinessName"‌​:"Red SpiceInc",
  "PrimaryContactFirstName":"Varma",
  "PrimaryContactLastName":"Bhupatiraju",
  "P‌​rimaryContactPhone":"(949) 374 2114",
  "PrimaryContactEmail":"redspice@mybusinessapp.com",
  "AccountGuid":"918D3E66-CEFE-11E0-8C2F-0C0B4824019B",
  "EntityState":1,"EntityKey":null}]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Stream p1:nil="true" xmlns:p1="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; />
```

**My code**

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetSetting({LocationGuid},{settingName})", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Stream GetSetting(string LocationGuid, string settingName)
{
    string str = string.Empty;
    string strJSON = string.Empty;
    dynamic contactResponse = new JsonObject();
    List<setting> Result;
    Result = new List<setting>();
    var Location = from acc in objEntity.locations where acc.LocationGuid == LocationGuid select acc;
    if (Location.Count() > 0)
    {
        var LocationId = (from acc in objEntity.locations where acc.LocationGuid == LocationGuid select acc).First();
        var objSetting = from cat in objEntity.settings where cat.SettingName == settingName & cat.LocationId == LocationId.LocationId select cat;
        setting SettingList = new setting();
        foreach (setting setting in objSetting)
        {
            setting Settinglist = new setting();
            Settinglist.SettingId = setting.SettingId;
            Settinglist.AccountId = setting.AccountId;
            Settinglist.LocationId = setting.LocationId;
            Settinglist.SettingName = setting.SettingName;
            Settinglist.SettingValue = setting.SettingValue;
            Settinglist.FieldType = setting.FieldType;
            Result.Add(Settinglist);
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        strJSON = js.Serialize(Result);
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strJSON));
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2011/9/returning_json_from_wcfwebapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe return the POCO is enough
the method signature is

```
public List<setting> GetSetting(string, string)
```

WCF Web API will serialize the object into json or xml for you as per your request header (accept: application/json, or application/xml)

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in misaxi's response, the WebApi `WebGet` operations generally do not need to concern themselves with how the response is returned.  The responsibility of the web operation is to simply return the data.  E.g....

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetSetting({LocationGuid},{settingName})"]
public List<setting> GetSetting(string LocationGuid, string settingName)
{
    List<setting> Result = null;
    var Location = from acc in objEntity.locations where acc.LocationGuid == LocationGuid select acc;
    if (Location.Count() > 0)
    {
        Result = new List<setting>();
        ....
        foreach (setting setting in objSetting)
        {
            ....
            Result.Add(Settinglist);
        }
     }
     return Result;
}
```

The fact that the client receives XML, JSON, JSONP, HTML, etc is up to the client (in conjunction with server-side support).  The client's request header will include something that looks like `Accept: application/json` or `Accept: application/xml` or whatever representation that the client is after.  WebApi comes pre-loaded with a few standard formats, XML (the default) and Json.  You can introduce more formats as needed to accept a more diverse set of `Accept: ....` headers, but the conversion from your data to these requested formats are generally out-of-scope for your web operation and rely on the formatters you set up (or were set up by default) when your service is initialized.

Likewise, `WebPost` operations generally do not care if the body of the request was XML or JSON, by the time the operation is invoked, formatters have already translated that payload into your method's parameters.